# Ошибка при проведении классификации с помощью нейронной сети

Tags: python, python-3.x, sklearn

```
#Используя набор данных, провести классификацию с помощью нейронной сети. 
#Данные: https://www.kaggle.com/dhruvildave/top-play-store-games
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
root_folder = "drive/My Drive/mypythondirectory"

import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

allColumns = pd.read_csv(root_folder+"/android_games.csv")

X = allColumns.drop(columns=['paid'])

encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y = encoder.fit_transform(allColumns['paid'])

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)

nn = MLPClassifier(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10)
)
nn.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print("Правильность на обучающем наборе : ", nn.score(X_train, Y_train))
print("Правильность на тестовом наборе: ", nn.score(X_test, Y_test))

nn = MLPClassifier(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10)
)

nn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Оценка точности: ", nn.score(X_train, Y_train))
print("Предсказание: ", nn.predict(X_test))
```

**Вылезают две ошибки, как решить?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не на всех текстовых полях применили `LabelEncoder`

Comment: Какие именно ошибки? Надо найти в каких колонках у вас текстовые данные, из ошибки мне непонятно, в каких именно. А так будет что-то типа `X['strcolumn'] = encoder.fit_transform(allColumns['strcolumb'])`

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня ошибки в колонке title там находятся названия игр и пишет что нельзя название игры конвертировать из string в float

Comment: Ну вот попробуйте применить тот код, который я написал выше, только к колонке `'title'`, соответственно, вместо условной `'strcolumn'`, которую я там написал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y = encoder.fit_transform(allColumns['paid'])

X['title'] = encoder.fit_transform(allColumns['title'])
X['installs'] = encoder.fit_transform(allColumns['installs'])
X['category'] = encoder.fit_transform(allColumns['category'])
```

Comment: Код добавляйте редактируя вопрос, а не в виде ответа. Вот вы добавили такой код - и какой результат?

Comment: @CrazyElf нужные столбцы закодировались